# NSString get text between certain characters

Tags: cocoa, macos, string

If I have an NSString with something like this in it: `Note Title Here:@:Note Description Here:@:123839:@:High Priority`
How can I separate out the strings between the ":@:" characters? I would know how many segments to expect if using something other than an array/for-loop would be easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take at look at the [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_35): method.  It should do what you want

```
[myString componentsSeparatedByString: @":@:"]
```

should give you an NSArray instance containing the parts of the string split out